# TextMate 2 - Smart Typing Pairs feature and tweaking

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I use the TextMate 2 SCSS bundle everyday.

It has a very annoying behavior: it "autocompletes" some stuff using the "Smart Typing Pairs" feature.

It's very useful most of the time (e.g. I type `(` and it types `)` automatically), but buy looking at the [source code](https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle/blob/master/Preferences/smart%20typing%20pairs.tmPreferences) you can see there's a not-so-intuitive autocompletion:

```
<string>:</string>
<string>;</string>
```

Ok, when I type: `background:` it turns it into `background:;`, and that's ok, but it also turns `a:not(:last-child)` into the incredibly annoying `a:not(:last-child);;`, which I have to clean every single time.

Now, since the TextMate manual is very brief when it mentions Smart Typing Pairs ([here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/preferences_items#paired_characters)), I would like to know how to solve this issue.

For example, can I use regexes to choose what to smart-complete? Or what to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing Alan the lead developer from the mailing list:

> For CSS this is the PropertyName setting in Bundles → CSS → Settings.
>   Currently it is scoped to ‘meta.property-list.css
>   -meta.property-value’ which should limit where it fires.
>
> Looking in [the SCSS bundle], it there is a Smart Typing Pairs setting
>   with the pair which is scoped to source.css. This appears to be wrong,
>   and it should instead mimic the CSS bundle wrt. only enabling it in
>   the context where it makes sense.

To do that, just set your `Bundle Editor` → `SCSS` → `Settings` → `Smart Typing Pairs` → `Scope Selector` to

```
meta.property-list.scss -meta.property-value
```